# npm install throws following error(running npm install on already developed apps)

Tags: node.js

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600

npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs
\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"

npm ERR! node v0.12.7

npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo EN
OTFOUND proxy-server-address

npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.

npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mayur\Documents\backend\baawarchi\npm-debug.log

Comment: Have you read the error?
Are you by chance behind a proxy?
Did you look into the mentioned `npm-debug.log`?

Comment: the debug log contains the same info........i m not behind a proxy.